# Difference b/w string concatenation and bind variables in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Pretty much title. I'd like to know if there are difference in behaviour and performance between string concatenation

```
var_name := 'SKING';
sql := 'select * from emp where ename = ' || var_name;
execute immediate sql;
```

and bind variables

```
sql := 'select * from emp where ename = :1';
execute immediate sql
using var_name;
```

in dynamic SQL. Thanks!

Comment: The second one is more secure, and prevents injection. Use it.

Comment: You should read up about [SQL injection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-1E31057E-057F-4A53-B1DD-8BC2C337AA2C) for a start. Also read about [parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/sql-processing.html#GUID-8CF633B1-EAC4-47C7-9189-C479ADEF1FFA).

Comment: Oracle caches cursors to save reparsing and reoptimising. Flooding that cache with one-time queries has a range of effects on a system, generally bad. You won’t be able to track a query’s performance over time, unrelated cursors get aged out of cache, the database burns more CPU, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potentially huge difference in behavior if `var_name` contains a string like

```
'A' AND 1=2 UNION SELECT password, null, null ... FROM users WHERE username='admin'
```

In the first example, you might just manipulate the DB into dumping the admin password (hashes) or other sensitive info. If this were done as a bind variable then you'd get 0 rows unless there really is an employee with the name `'A' AND 1=2 UNION ...`

The first query will even cause a crash if your employee's name is a far more innocuous `Peter O'Toole` or something else with a legitimate ' character

https://bobby-tables.com goes into some detail about SQL injection hacking

Always, always, always use bind variables. There is never an excuse for string concatenating **values** into a query, when you can concatenate a **variable name** in instead

--

As for performance, it can help the database query optimizer plan queries and cache execution plans if it knows which parts of a query are subject to variation and which parts are fixed. If you concatenate values in, it can't tell the difference between something you're declaring you might vary next time and something that remains the same

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_type = 'manager' and emp_name = :name
```

Above, the optimizer can easily deduce that this query will always only return manager types, though the name may vary, This can influence data access and indexing strategies and can have performance implications. It's hard to be concrete about what, because the optimizer is something of a black box; but rest assured that it strives to deliver the best performance from the information available because of good old capitalism/market forces (who buys a slow db?) so help it out..